# Possible problem of gcc with sleep_for and sleep_until functions

Tags: c++, gcc, time, thread-sleep, systemtime

**gcc** seems to have a problem with sleep_for and sleep_until functions (of namespace std::this_thread). I do some simple example with future and conditional variables. **gcc** actually uses the ***System Clock instead of Monotonic Clock*** and this can cause jumps over time. In my example in some case the clock jumps afterward and my timeout expires immediately.

The Bug should be this [GCC Bug 41861](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41861)

I see that in the future gcc 10 release the bug maybe is resolved, but until the realease of the new version of gcc there is a solution for this problem? Someone have noted that?

UPDATE:
This Bug is resolved or not yet in the last compiler version ( GCC 10.2 )?

Comment: _" I don't post the code of my example because are very simple test and i trashed them"_, well that's unfortunate. I'd advise you to rewrite them.

Comment: Don't use those functions, I suppose? Or tell your users not to change the clock while your program is running? (or don't tell them that until they ask you about it)

Comment: relevant part of the Standard: https://eel.is/c++draft/thread.req.timing#3 _"The functions whose names end in _­for take an argument that specifies a duration.
These functions produce relative timeouts.
Implementations should use a steady clock to measure time for these functions."_

Comment: I seem to recall this is a known issue that I came across years ago. Will try to come up with some references

Comment: @YSC i read this, but i noticed that the compiler doesn't do what the standard says.

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 thank you so much, all amswer are appreciated

Comment: however the code are the simple example of the c++reference site with some timestamp placed in the right place.

Comment: I dont post my answer because it was simple and I trashed it. Sorry, couldnt resist :P. Seriously, an example that is very simple is the best example, you should post it

Comment: An example would be interesting (and the question should have included a link to the GCC bug page), but we don't need code to answer the question "how can I work around X known issue in Y software until version Z?"

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 I correct the text of my question with the bug link thank you so much

Comment: It's worth noting that that bug does not contain any code change to fix the problem for `this_thread`. There may be another one which is the one you're actually referring to. Where did you get the information that it was fixed in GCC 10?

Answer (score 4):

This is indeed a stunning bug, fixed in GCC 10 ([bug 41861](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41861) describes it in the context of `<condition_variable>`).

Back in the day when I encountered this, it was tempting to fall back on Boost to get the proper behaviour, but [even that was broken until 1.61](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4381095/560648). And nowadays it would be strange to mix Boost and standard timing/threading code anyway, since the standard facilities are generally mature and preferred (irony detected!).

What I did at the time was to create a replacement for `condition_variable` that wrapped POSIX functionality directly.

Whatever you're doing with `sleep_for`/`sleep_until`, I suspect you have little recourse but to do the same thing, sorry.